# Set a custom size grip in QStatusBar in PyQt4

Tags: python, image, icons, pyqt4, stylesheet

How do i set a custom SizeGrip-icon in the lower right corner? I don't find any snippets and can't figure out. The only snippets are for a QSizeGrip and not for a grip inside a QStatusBar. Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(400,100)

        self.setStyleSheet("QStatusBar{background:green; image=url('/home/me/grip.png')}")

        self.layout=QVBoxLayout()        
        self.layout.setMargin(0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.bottom=QStatusBar()
        self.bottom.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.bottom)        

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        pic=QFile()
        pic.setFileName("/home/me/grip.png")
        if QFile.exists(pic):
            print("pic found")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    a=Main()
    a.show()
    app.exec_()
```

My check for the file returns that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QSS for this:

```
 QSizeGrip {
     image: url(:/images/sizegrip.png);
     width: 16px;
     height: 16px;
 }
```